# How to search records in all directory except one in Marklogic

Tags: search, directory, marklogic

I am trying to search XML's in my database using marklogic-java api with following restrictions :

1) A particular XML tag must contain my given value for ex : tradeId must equal to what I pass

2) Results must lie in collections provided  by me

3) Results can lie anywhere in marklogic database except in one particular directory

I don't have the solution to point 3. Few of the records meeting my first two criteria have a URI starting with /TRADES/* and so i want to search everywhere except under directory "/TRADES".

This is how my code looks :

```
public static List<DocumentPage> getResults() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {


    String tradeId = "XYZ";

    DatabaseClient client = getDBClient();
    QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
    XMLDocumentManager xmlMngr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();

    StringHandle rawHandle = new StringHandle();
    rawHandle.withFormat(Format.XML).set(getQueryToFetchMessagesByTradeId(tradeId));
    RawQueryByExampleDefinition querydef = queryMgr.newRawQueryByExampleDefinition(rawHandle);

    querydef.setCollections("/messages/processed", /messages/toBeProcessed");
    querydef.setDirectory("/");

    return getDocumentPageList(querydef, client);
}

private static String getQueryToFetchMessagesByTradeId(String tradeId) {

    String query = "<q:qbe xmlns:q=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/querybyexample\">\n" + "<q:query>\n<q:word>"
            + "<tradeId tradeIdScheme=" + "\"http://www.abcd.com/internalid/trade-id\"" + ">" + tradeId
            + "</tradeId></q:word>\n" + "</q:query>\n" + "</q:qbe>";
    return query;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about Java implementation, but `cts:not-query(cts:directory-query("TRADES","1"))` would be the XQuery equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an option to compose metadata (directory) queries in query by example syntax.  So you'll have to use Structured Queries instead.  I find them more readable in Java anyway since they don't require string concatenation.  Use StructuredQueryBuilder like so:

```
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
StructuredQueryDefinition querydef =
  qb.and(
      qb.containerQuery(
        qb.element(new QName("http://www.abcd.com/internalid/trade-id", "tradeId")),
        qb.and(
          qb.term( tradeId ),
          qb.value(
            qb.elementAttribute(
              qb.element(new QName("http://www.abcd.com/internalid/trade-id", "tradeId")),
              qb.attribute("tradeIdScheme")
            ),
            "http://www.abcd.com/internalid/trade-id"
          )
        )
      ),
      qb.not(
        qb.directory(1, "/TRADES/")
      )
  );

querydef.setCollections("/messages/processed", "/messages/toBeProcessed")

return getDocumentPageList(querydef, client);
```

Comment: Hi Sam

I need to search only the XMLs which have following XML tag:

<tradeId tradeIdScheme="http://www.myorganization.com/internalid/trade-id">"MY_TRADE_ID"</tradeId>

The code provided by you works fine without QNAME check, however the moment I pass it the tradeIdScheme attribute value and actual tradeid in QName, it fails.

Referring to your code, Can you tell me how to search an XMLTag with a particular attribute value and containing a particular value.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I updated my answer to include the attribute query.